# How to change the default file type from webm to gif for 30s ubuntu screencasts?

Tags: ubuntu, gif, webm, screencast

Ubuntu provides an option to record a screencast of 30s by `Ctrl + Shift + Alt + R`.

The default file type is `webm`. How do I set the default to `gif`?

**It is wastage to time to convert these files to gif using an online converter.**

*Instead, I would like them to be saved in gif format by default.*

Comment: What are you using the GIF for? It’s an outdated format, and even giphy uses video, so if you upload it on a GIF platform, it will be reconverted to video any way.

Comment: this question is one year old, and you are asking my need for gif now ? actually i no more need gifs. long ago, github issues supported adding only gifs. now they support video as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a great tool to record gifs
https://github.com/phw/peek

[image: Peek recording itself]

Answer (score 2):

#### Ubuntu records 30s .webm screencasts in Videos Folder via Ctrl+Shift+Alt+R, automatically convert them to GIF in Pictures Folder, and delete video file

---

```sh
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/aahnik/Videos
for f in *.webm;
do 
ffmpeg -i "$f" ../Pictures/"$f"_gif.gif;
rm "$f";
done
```

Make sure to have `ffmpeg` installed

- Save the `toGIF.sh` in your Videos folder, [link](https://gist.github.com/aahnik/6ee62e9f9b08b33632958bad4604ee18#file-togif-sh)
- make it executable `chmod +x /home/Videos/toGIF.sh`
- Go to Settings ---> Keyboard Shortcuts ---> New ShortCut
- Set a new shortcut like this

[image: Screenshot from 2020-09-10 22-22-16]

*note: the command should be the path to shell script*

- now whenever you take short screencasts, via default `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+R`, execute the `Shift+Ctrl+ALt+G`
- the script will run in background and **convert all .webm in Videos folder to .gif in Pictures Folder, and delete video file.**
- Please let the screencast finish, and then initiate the conversion to GIF, otherwise, the GIF will be incomplete and the video will get deleted before its 30s duration.

Please take a look below for better understanding.

**Step 1**

[image: Screencast from 10-09-20 10:41:39 PM IST webm_gif]

**Step 2**

[image: Screencast from 10-09-20 10:42:49 PM IST webm_gif]